# Unexpected T_ELSE error in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax-error

I am working on an example from a php book and am getting an error on line 8 with this code

```
<?php

$agent = getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");
if (preg_match("/MSIE/i", "$agent"));
{
    $result = "You are using Microsoft Internet Explorer";
}
else if (preg_match("/Mozilla/i", "$agent")); 
{
    $result = "You are using Mozilla firefox";
}
else {$result = "you are using $agent"; }

echo $result;


?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$agent = getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");
if (preg_match("/MSIE/i", $agent)) {
  $result = "You are using Microsoft Internet Explorer";
} else if (preg_match("/Mozilla/i", $agent)) {
  $result = "You are using Mozilla firefox";
} else {
  $result = "you are using $agent";
}

echo $result;
```

Two things:

1. You had a semi-colon at the end of your if clauses. That means the subsequent opening brace was a local block that is always executed. That caused a problem because later you had an `else` statement that wasn't attached to an `if` statement; and
2. Doing `"$agent"` is unnecessary and not recommended. Simply pass in `$agent`.

Answer (score 16):

There are `;` at the end of `if` statements.

**Cause of error:**

```
if(...) ;
{
...
}
```

Will **not** cause any syntax error as the body of `if` is *empty* and the following block *always* gets executed. But

```
if(...) ;
{
  // blk A
} else {
...
}
```

will cause `Unexpected else` syntax error because the `if` as before has empty body and is followed by another block `blk A` which is not if's body. Now when an `else` if found after the block it ***cannot*** be matched with any `if` causing this error. The same would happen if we'd `statement`(s) in place of a block:

```
if(...) ;
 do_something;
else {
...
}
```

Comment: Excellent and thorough analysis!

Answer (score 3):

remove the semi-colons from the end of the lines with "if" in them.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have a semicolon here? `if (preg_match("/MSIE/i", "$agent"));` and here `else if (preg_match("/Mozilla/i", "$agent"));`